# Javax.mail скрыть отображение в консоли

Tags: отладка, email, java

Доброй ночи.
Никак не удается отключить отображение текста от javax.mail. Мне нужно полностью скрыть все эти сообщения.
Я всего лишь отправляю сообщение через gmail.
Искал в гугле, искал в книгах, кроме setDebug(false) ничего так и не могу найти. Но и это не совсем то..
А вот как выглядит текст:

http://screenshot.ru/images/2013/10/05/ZDIr.png

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте props.put("mail.debug", "false");
НО! есть такой момент, что в версии 1.4 в SNTP транспорте, вывод некоторой информации не завязан на флаг дебага, т.е. там вполне себе написано просто System.out.println... говорят в 1.5 поправили...обновите библиотеку может сработает...